# Show that a sequence converges to $l \in ]1,2[$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $E=\{p \in \mathbb{N}^{*^\mathbb{N}} / p_1 \geq 2,\ p_{n+1} \geq
> p_n^2\}$
>
> To each $p \in E$, we associate $(u_n)_{n\geq 1}$, $u_n = \prod_{1\leq
> k \leq n} (1 + \frac{1}{p_k})$
>
> I've shown that for $a \in ]0,1[$, $(1-a)(\prod_{0\leq k \leq n}(1 +
>  a^{2^k})) \leq 1$

The question is to show that the sequence associated with $p \in E$ is convergent and the limit $l$ is in $]1,2] $

What I tried is that: $\prod (1 + \frac{1}{p_n}) \leq u_n \leq \prod(1 + \frac{1}{p_1})$

Plus: $p_{n} \geq p_{n-1}^2$, $p_{n} \geq P_{n-2}^4,\  \dots\ ,\ p_{n} \geq p_1^{2^n}$

So $p_n \geq 2^{(2^n)}$. I tried to use that for getting rid of the "$p_n$" on the left side and then use somehow the inequality but it won't work because $\prod (1+ \frac{1}{p_n}) \leq \prod (1 + \frac{1}{2^{(2^n)}})$ and not the other way. Any idea or any advise?

Edit: the limit is in $]1,2]$ and not $]1,2 [$